# Number of Hole in a simplicial complex

Tags: algebraic-topology, simplicial-complex

I was going over Example 2.10 of [Botnan, Magnus Bakke. "Topological Data Analysis Spring 2020."](https://www.few.vu.nl/%7Ebotnan/lecture_notes.pdf).

I thought the number of holes is 3 which includes the hole from the linear combination of c1+c2.. but seems not. Could someone tell me why not?

### Example 2.10

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Today, I presented this exercise to my colleagues and After a discussion w/h them, we realised that $Z_1(K)$ actually contains linear combinations of cycles as they are mapped to zero, i.e., they form a kernel!, so the 3 coming from dim$Z_1(K)$ was covering my case!